# Custom Menu not functioning properly

Tags: menus

I register 2 menus in  my functions.php file:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'main_menu' => 'Main Menu',
    'bottom_menu' => 'Bottom Menu'
));
```

I populate a menu in the admin and assign the theme location:

[image: Assigning menu location]

I call the menu in my theme:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu('menu', 'main_menu');
?>
```

After doing all this, `bottom_menu` is the menu showing up in my theme instead.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Either I'm missing something really silly here or Wordpress is giving me the finger.

Comment: [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) takes array of arguments, see usage examples in documentation.

Comment: Resolved! It was the `theme_location` argument.

Answer (score 2):

By specifying a `theme_location` argument in my array, the issue was fixed:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'main_menu'
));
```

#### Edit

For a distributed Theme, do *not* pass the `'menu'` parameter to the `wp_nav_menu()` call. It will look for a specific slug of a user-created menu, and will override `'theme_location'`. Only ever pass `'theme_location'`.